# My sorting algorithm says :Your code did not execute within the time limits. how to solve this problem

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, swap

I have designed an algorithm for sorting an array with minimum number of swaps. The array is consist of consecutive number from 1 to n. When I run this program it gives an erorr that "Your code did not execute within the time limits" How to Solve this ?

```
static int minimumSwaps(int[] arr) {
    int n = arr.length;
    int swap = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr[i] != (i + 1)) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[temp - 1];
                arr[temp - 1] = temp;
                swap++;
            }
        }
    }
    return swap;
}
```

Comment: What is the maximum *time* allowed?

Comment: Your code frequently confuses indexes and values from the array. `if (arr[i] != (i + 1)) {` for instance, and `int temp = arr[i];` followed by `arr[i] = arr[temp - 1];`. Is the data set specially designed in some way?

Comment: I don't know . This is a hackerrank question. I checked the failed testcase it has a huge size of array so the problem is time complexity but I don't know how to execute my idea with less time complexity or using just one loop.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the question?

Comment: You should elaborate more on where the "Your code did not execute within the time limits" comes from. Alternatively (preferably) you ask the actual question "how to speed up the code?" The fact that you're running this in a leaderboard framework is not relevant, I guess...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes the data is from 1 to n . All consevutive digits like position of '11' in sorted array will be 10 if we start the index from 0. What i m doing here is ,  swapping the arr[i] digit to arr[i]-1 position.

Comment: @Glains https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/minimum-swaps-2/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays

Comment: i came across your post with a similar question regarding time complexity, and I have found this video very helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6xkbGLQesk

Answer (score 3):

For competitive programming problems like this, before you even start writing any code, you should think about the input sizes you have to deal with and what time complexity your algorithm needs. For HackerRank, an input of size n <= 10^5 generally means your algorithm has to run in O(*n* log *n*) time, if not O(*n*) time.

The algorithm you have written takes O(*n*²) time, and you could have derived this before writing any code; it uses two nested loops, each of which iterate *n* times, so the number of iterations is *n* times *n*. That means there is no way this algorithm is fast enough for inputs of size 10^5 on HackerRank, and you need a fundamentally different algorithm.

Because you know the array elements are the numbers from 1 to *n* with no duplicates or missing values, this problem can in fact be solved in O(*n*) time. The trick is to think of the input array as a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of the numbers 1 to *n*. All permutations can be represented using [cycle notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation) as a composition of disjoint cycles: for example, the permutation `3 5 4 1 2` is composed of the cycles `(1 3 4)(2 5)` since the permutation maps `1 → 3`, `3 → 4`, `4 → 1`, and `2 → 5` and `5 → 2`. It's a mathematical fact that a cycle of length *k* takes (*k* - 1) swaps to "do" or "undo". So, the answer to the problem can be found as the sum of (*k* - 1) for each cycle.

There is a straightforward algorithm to find the cycles of a permutation in linear time, using a set to keep track of which elements have already been "used" in order to iteratively find the first "unused" value which will be the start of the next cycle. Alternatively, you can change the values in the array to some sentinel (e.g. -1) to indicate that they have already been used, to do it without an auxiliary data structure.